# Power BI DAX - formula referencing itself

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am struggling to recreate the following Excel logic in DAX:

[logic for the bottom level](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7f4c.png)

[logic for all levels above the bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ShezD.png)

**Amount** is a dynamic measure calculated in an earlier step and **Target weight** is a data column (sourced from SharePoint list).

There are 12 levels in the data so I created 12 separate measures starting from the lowest level (0) and going up (11). But there's not enough memory in PBI to complete all calculations for the highest level.

I'm using measures so that I can apply multiple filters - I need calculations to be dynamic.

Any tips & solutions would be much appreciated. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

1. Create two measures:

   Amount Measure = SUM('Table'[Amount])
   Target weight Measure = SUM('Table'[Target weight])
2. Calculate the column:

   Column =
   VAR L3=3
   VAR A3=CALCULATE([Amount Measure]/[Target weight Measure],'Table'[Level]=L3,ALLEXCEPT('Table','Table'[Level]))
   VAR L2=2
   VAR A2=(CALCULATE([Amount Measure],'Table'[Level]=L2,ALLEXCEPT('Table','Table'[Level]))+A3)/CALCULATE([Target weight Measure],'Table'[Level]=L2,ALLEXCEPT('Table','Table'[Level]))
   VAR L1=1
   VAR A1=(CALCULATE([Amount Measure],'Table'[Level]=L1,ALLEXCEPT('Table','Table'[Level]))+A2)/CALCULATE([Target weight Measure],'Table'[Level]=L1,ALLEXCEPT('Table','Table'[Level]))
   VAR L0=0
   VAR A0=(CALCULATE([Amount Measure],'Table'[Level]=L0,ALLEXCEPT('Table','Table'[Level]))+A1)/CALCULATE([Target weight Measure],'Table'[Level]=L0,ALLEXCEPT('Table','Table'[Level]))
   Return
   SWITCH(TRUE(),
   [Level]=L3,A3,
   [Level]=L2,A2,
   [Level]=L1,A1,
   [Level]=L0,A0)

Result as below:

[image]

If the [level] is more than 3 then you can add new sentences followed by the rule. I am not sure if it's the easiest way. Please let me know if anyone eles has more smart formula. Thanks!